# Passing objects between Components/Pages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular6

Hello Im passing objects between two pages. 
I have two pages in Ionic App. The first page has Defect object and sends it to the second page. The second Page receives the object and calls it's methods. Passing objects is done with usage of NavParams, an Ionic core class. Below you can see the receiving of the object. The Defect object.

```
export class Defect {
  public priority: DefectPriority;
  public state: DefectState;
  public note: string;
  public _id: string;
  public posX: number;
  public posY: number;
  public createdAt: number;
  public drawingId: string;
  public images: DefectImage[];

  constructor();
  constructor(posY?: number, posX?: number, note?: string, defectId?: string, drawingId?: string) {
    if (defectId === undefined || defectId === "") {
      throw new Error("incorrect defect id");
    }
    if (posX === undefined || posY === undefined) {
      throw new Error("incorrect coordinates");
    }
    if (drawingId === undefined || drawingId === "") {
      throw new Error("incorrect drawingId");
    }
    if (drawingId === undefined || drawingId === "") {
      throw new Error("incorrect drawingId");
    }
    this.priority = DefectPriority.NORMAL;
    this.createdAt = new Date().getTime();
    this.state = DefectState.REPORTED;
    this._id = defectId;
    this.note = note;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.drawingId = drawingId;
    this.images = [];
  }

  public getPriority() {
    return this.priority;
  }

  setPriority(value: DefectPriority) {
    if (!Object.values(DefectPriority).includes(value.toString())) {
      throw new Error("incorrect priority")
    }
    this.priority = value;
  }

  public changeState(value: DefectState) {
    this.state = value;
  }

  public setNote(note: string) {
    this.note = note;
  }

  generateImageUrl(creatorName: string): DefectImage {
    const newUrl = ObjectId.generate() + '-' + this._id + '.jpg';
    const defectImage = new DefectImage(newUrl, creatorName, new Date().getMilliseconds());
    this.addImage(defectImage);
    return defectImage;
  }

  addImage(defectImage: DefectImage) {
    if (!this.images) {
      this.images = [];
    }
    this.images.push(defectImage);
  }
```

Here is the receiving class:

```
defect: Defect;

  constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController,
              private nav: NavParams,
              private navCtrl: NavController,
              private photo: PhotoProvider) {
    this.defect = this.nav.get('defect');
  }
```

Defect class apart from some properties has also methods like: `generateImageUrl`

**Now when I change view to the component where the defect is beeing fetched from params internally it is just JS object without information about Defect class methods:** Which means I cannot call methods defined in defect class after I send it to the another Page.

[image]

Notice no custom methods like `generateImageUrl`. Is there a way that I could not lose informations about this object? Or should I just recreate this object from data in the new component ?? my goal on screen below:
[image]

the way Im passing data:

```
const defectModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DefectDetailModal, {
      defect: this.defect
    });
```

Comment: It would help if you could add some more details on what exactly it is that you're trying to share. A little bit of context goes a long way.

Comment: did my best. If oyu have more question let me know

Comment: Okay so `Defect` is a class and you're passing an instance of the `Defect` class as `NavParams`. Why exactly are you doing that though? Don't you think it's going to have an import on your App Navigation? What exactly is your rationale behind passing such a huge Object?

Comment: I am passing this object so that i can edit it in the new place

Comment: can you show the way  that you pass defect  object?

Comment: If you cast the object to the Defect type does that do anything?
`this.defect = this.nav.get('defect') as Defect;`

Comment: nope it gets converted to json-alike object in navParams, in my unusual case I will just recreate obejct from the copy on the second page

Comment: did you stringify  the object before passing?

Comment: nope but it gets strigified by the framework

Comment: can you try stringify manually before pass, and prase after receive?

Comment: thats what i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Defect` is an entity in your App. [**Angular's Style Guide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) recommends using `interface`s for data models instead of `class`es.

> Consider using an interface for data models.

That being said, you should have created a DefectService, where you would have set some property for the current defect that you're dealing with.

You could have then injected the service in the components that you wanted to share data between. Then from one component, you could have set the defect and then you could get the defect in the other component using `set`ters and `get`ters.

Comment: I think good solution here could be to use behaviour subject and then get it from there, would work like service you describe